# Unrar an archive in C#

Tags: c#, .net, command-line, cmd, compression

I want to silent extract of `.rar` archive. .Net haven't any Rar classes in IO.Compression, so i'd like to use cmd (it's better, than external dll). It extracts, but not in silent mode. What am I doing wrong?

```
const string source = "D:\\22.rar";
string destinationFolder = source.Remove(source.LastIndexOf('.'));
string arguments = string.Format(@"x -s ""{0}"" *.* ""{1}\""", source, destinationFolder);
Process.Start("winrar", arguments);
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I use this bit of code myself (your code added):

```
const string source = "D:\\22.rar";
string destinationFolder = source.Remove(source.LastIndexOf('.'));
System.Diagnostics.Process p = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
p.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
p.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
p.StartInfo.FileName = "\"C:\\Program Files\\WinRAR\\winrar.exe\"";
p.StartInfo.Arguments = string.Format(@"x -s ""{0}"" *.* ""{1}\""", source, destinationFolder);
p.Start();
p.WaitForExit();
```

That will launch the WinRAR program in the background and return control to you once the file has completed un-rar-ing.

Hope that can help

Answer (score 3):

Use SharpCompress https://github.com/adamhathcock/sharpcompress/blob/master/USAGE.md
there is also a nuget package for easy installation.

```
Install-Package sharpcompress -Version 0.22.0
```

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, you can embed with your application the tool called unRAR, the small executable developed by the WinRAR's developers ([official download](http://www.rarlab.com/rar_add.htm)).

This utility is free, thus your users won't need to have a WinRAR license to use your application. :) It can be executed using the same way **txtechhelp** described.

Answer (score 0):

Use NUnrar, there is also a nuget package for easy installation.

```
Install-Package nunrar

NUnrar.Archive.RarArchive.WriteToDirectory(fileName,destinationfileName);
```

Answer (score 0):

As Mihail Shishkov suggested it's possible to unrar files with [SharpCompress](https://github.com/adamhathcock/sharpcompress) library.

```bash
dotnet add package SharpCompress
```

Here is a basic usage example:

```cs
var archive = RarArchive.Open("/Downloads/archive.rar");

foreach (var entry in archive.Entries.Where(entry => !entry.IsDirectory))
    entry.WriteToDirectory("/Downloads");
```

I tried to use it in .NET 6 application under macOS and it works fine.