# Extract split rar file

Tags: c#, rar, sevenzipsharp

I need to extract a splitted rar-file (r00, r01, r02,...) in C#.

The only thing I've found that might be useful, is sevenzipsharp. I cannot find an example of what I'm trying to do though.

Someone said "docs available at https://archive.codeplex.com/?p=sevenzipsharp", but that dosen't really help since I can't find any examples there.

I know that everything would be a lot easier if I use a different compression format, but I'm not responsible for the generation of the zip files so that is unfortunately not an option.

*** UPDATE 01/17/2019 ***

I tried:

```
namespace test
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            // Toggle between the x86 and x64 bit dll
            var path = Path.Combine(Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location), Environment.Is64BitProcess ? "x64" : "x86", "7z.dll");
            SevenZip.SevenZipBase.SetLibraryPath(path);

            using (var file = new SevenZipExtractor(@"F:\ziptest\test.part1.rar"))
            {
                file.ExtractArchive(@"F:\dav\");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But that gives me an error, when calling "ExtractArchive":

```
An unhandled exception of type 'SevenZip.SevenZipArchiveException' occurred in SevenZipSharp.dll

Additional information: Invalid archive: open/read error! Is it encrypted and a wrong password was provided?
```

*** UPDATE 01/20/2019 ***

I ended up using the solution provide here:
[Unrar an archive in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23578704/unrar-an-archive-in-c-sharp)

I modified the switch parameters so that WinRar runs in the background without opening any windows.

If someone do come up with a solution to my problems with SevenZipSharp I would still like to know, as it is a more "clean" code.

Comment: If you read the link you provided, it says `See SevenZipTest/Program.cs for simple code examples; SevenZipTestForms is the GUI demo application.`

Answer (score 0):

The codeplex site has a discussion forum that shows several github forks. I followed one to this sample: https://github.com/squid-box/SevenZipSharp/blob/dev/SevenZip.Tests/SevenZipExtractorTests.cs#L64 which suggests that you just need to pass the first volume to the SevenZipExtractor constructor.

```
using (var extractor = new SevenZipExtractor(@"TestData\multivolume.part0001.rar")) {
    extractor.ExtractArchive(OutputDirectory);
}
```

Comment: Doesn't work. Still the same error.

Comment: It worked for me. I'm using .NET8.0. Just run the unit test referenced above (it passes). I then modified the test to point to the first file of my multivolume set and output to my save folder. When I rerun the test, it passes and writes the extracted file(s) to my save folder.